# How to get hidden packages with DevicePolicyManager?

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

I am implementing an application that uses DevicePolicyManager. I have provisioned my device using adb and my app is running on device admin mode.

I am using setApplicationHidden method to hide/unhide applications using their package name. I want to do a whitelist system where I can specify a few apps to not disable and I want to disable the rest of the apps installed on the phone. I can hide the apps that are not on my whitelist but once they are hidden I cannot get any info about them using packagemanager or any other method.

All I can get the information about unhidden applications.

Is there a way I can retrive this information without storing the package names of the apps I've hidden somewhere?

Comment: Maybe store the package info before hiding them? Does using the MATCH_DISABLED_COMPONENTS (or its earlier equiv.) flag work?

Comment: Actually, it seems MATCH_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES should work. You'll probably still need to know the package names though.

Answer (score 3):

So, the correct answer was actually given in the comments. Just have tested it and it works perfectly fine, including getting the *ApplicationInfo* and label.

To get the full list of packages on a device (including hidden by *DevicePolicyManger*) you should include flags: `MATCH_DISABLED_COMPONENTS | MATCH_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES`

```
context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(MATCH_DISABLED_COMPONENTS | MATCH_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
```

Answer (score 2):

I too have been searching for this answer.

This is not ideal but will return all packages to include hidden and disabled.

```
Runtime.getRuntime("pm list packages -u").exec();
```

here is how I use it

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String response = output.toString();
```

That gives you a all package names, however if you try and use them with PackageManager you will get a NameNotFoundException unless you unhide them first.